# Center a fieldset in an HTML page

Tags: css

I want to center a `fieldset` in my page but I don't know how.

I used this css code :

```
fieldset
{
    margin:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

but it only center the content of the `fieldset`
I also used a `<p style="text-align:center;"> <fieldset> ...</fieldset></p>`
but it wont work.

so how can I center it ?

**Edit :**

The `CSS` code I'm using now :

```
fieldset
{
    text-align:left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

div
{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried nesting the fieldset in a centered `<div>` with a set width?

Comment: Not truly a answer, but i would have a look at Twitter Bootstrap (excellent framework). http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: @JulesMazur thanks div has worked but it only center the `fieldset` horizontally I want to center it also vertically

Comment: @FADWAFDIWA you may try `vertical-align` or maybe `line-height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to position the element absolutely, offsetting the div by 50% from the left and the top part of the window and move the div to the left and to the top with half its width and height with a negative margin, to have it perfectly centered.

and this is the `CSS` code:

```
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add `text-align:center` to the parent element (maybe wrap it in a div and play with it if it's by itself.) to actually center the *element* and not the content. See if that works.

Comment: Yes it worked but it center also the content ANd I want only the `fieldset` to be centered I have removed the `text-align:center` from `fieldset` but it seems like the parent content which is `div` centers the `fieldset` and it's `content`

Comment: @FADWAFDIWA if you don't want your fieldset's text to be centered add for e.g. `text-align:left` to fieldset's property, that should work!

Comment: Okey, thanks it worked as I seed to @JulesMazur I want the `fieldset` to be also centered vertically

Comment: @FADWAFDIWA you may try `vertical-align` or maybe `line-height`, you are going to have to play around with height and margins if that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display` attribute. It needs to be a block element (which it is by default) for `margin: auto` to work. Or do you need it for something?

Comment: I can't remove the `display` attibute I'm using it to stretch the content of the fieldset

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    #fieldset{
   border-color:blue;
   border-radius:10px;
   margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
   position:absolute;
   left:50%;
   top:50%;
    }
```

But I do not the line margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;